# How do I sort an array of arrays to make it the most like an identity matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, matrix

I've tried many different algorithms, but can't find on that works.

So basically I'll have a matrix

```
1 0 1 | 4
7 0 1 | 9
1 1 3 | 3
```

And I'll want to get sort it so that it most resembles the identity matrix

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

So, for the previous matrix, it would return

```
1 0 1 | 4
1 1 3 | 3
7 0 1 | 9
```

Can anyone tell me a sorting function that will do this, preferably in javascript?

This is what I have so far

```
matrix.sort(function(a,b) {
      if (b.indexOf(1)!=-1) {
          var index =  a.indexOf(1)-b.indexOf(1)
          if (index!==0) return index
              else {
                  return b.indexOf(0) - a.indexOf(0)
              }
      }
      else {
          return 0
      }
})
```

A few more examples

```
3  1 -2 | 2
1 -2  1 | 3
2 -1 -3 | 3
```

would turn into

```
1 -2  1 | 3
3  1 -2 | 2 
2 -1 -3 | 3
```

and

```
 3  1 -2 | -7
 2  2  1 |  9
-1 -1  3 |  6
```

would turn into

```
-1 -1  3 |  6
 3  1 -2 | -7
 2  2  1 |  9
```

Comment: It would be easier to grok if you actually posted arrays, and explained how the examples relates to each other, as it's not very clear ?

Comment: What does it mean to "most resemble the identity matrix"? Do you just want 1s across the diagonal and 0s elsewhere. Or should the difference between the matrices be close to "0"?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to implement the first step of sorting the rows http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrix.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to String Metrics. In other words, your algorithm should be modeled off of string metric/distance algorithms, such as the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Basically, your algorithm needs to define how you want to rank similarity. 
This is usually done using points for 'displacement' and 'matching'.

What's closer to 100 - 010 or 000 ?

You should decide how to rank the similarity and then find the set that ranks the highest.

Comment: Glad to help! Do you mind accepting/voting if this answer is useful?

Comment: I would, but I don't have enough reputation yet :( If one more person upvotes this question I will.

Answer (score 0):

My final code:

```
    function(matrix) {
            var newmatrix = matrix.slice(0)
            var sorted = []
            var id = identity(newmatrix.length)
            for ( var i = 0; i < id.length; i++ ) {
                    var bestindex;
                    var bestdist = 100
                    for ( var j = 0; j < newmatrix.length; j++ ) {
                            var idstr = id[i].join('')
                            var matstr = newmatrix[j].join('')
                            var newdist = levenshteinDistance(idstr,matstr)
                            if (newdist < bestdist) {
                                    bestdist = newdist
                                    bestindex = j
                            }
                    }
                    sorted[i] = newmatrix[bestindex]
                    newmatrix.splice(bestindex,1)
            }
            return sorted
    }
    function levenshteinDistance(s, t) {
            if (s.length === 0) return t.length;
            if (t.length === 0) return s.length;
            return Math.min(
                    levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t) + 1,
                    levenshteinDistance(t.substr(1), s) + 1,
                    levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t.substr(1)) + (s[0] !== t[0] ? 1 : 0)
            );
    }
    function identity(n) {
            var id = []
            for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    id[i]=[]
                    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                            id[i][j] = (i===j) ? 1 : 0
                    }
            }
            return id
    }
```

I used the for loop, because it's more important that the items at the beginning of the array match than the end. Thanks a million to @Etai for the formula!